# Spring Boot BatchAcknowledgingMessageListener<String, String> Splitting Message on Commas

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have a Spring Boot app with a Kafka Listener implementing the BatchAcknowledgingMessageListener<String, String> interface. When I receive what should be a single message from the topic, it's actually one message for each line in the original message, and I can't cast the message to a ConsumerRecord<String, String>.

The code producing the record looks like this:

```
this.kafkaTemplate.send("myTopic", "12345", "{\"OrderID\": \"12345\"}, \"OrderDate\": \"2021-06-01T12:13:16Z\"");
```

And the Kafka configuration looks like this (this is still in the integration test phase using Testcontainers, so the producer is producing on the same topic the consumer is listening to):

```yaml
spring:
  kafka:
    listener:
      ack-mode: manual-immediate
      concurrency: 1
    consumer:
      bootstrap-servers: localhost:9093
      enable-auto-commit: false
      group-id: my-group
      auto-offset-reset: earliest
      key-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
      value-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
      max-poll-records: 10
      topic: myTopic
    producer:
      bootstrap-servers: localhost:9093
      client-id: my-client
      key-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
      value-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
      topic: myTopic
```

And finally, the consumer logic:

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "${spring.kafka.consumer.topic}")
public void consumeMessages(final List<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> records, final Acknowledgment ack) throws IOException {
  // This line fails with ClassCastException: "Can't cast String to ConsumerRecord"
  // for (final ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {

  for (final Object record : records) {
    log.debug("Record: {}", record);
  }
  ...
}
```

The debug output from this example is:

```
[LOG HEADER]: Record: {"OrderID": "12345"
[LOG HEADER]: Record: "OrderDate": "2021-06-01T12:13:16Z"}
```

As you can see, the message is being split on commas, and I'm receiving multiple messages for the single message that was produced. This is obviously failing, but I can't figure out why I'm not just getting the single ConsumerRecord<String, String> object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the listener type configuration so the default conversion service sees you want a list and splits the string by commas.

```yaml
spring:
  kafka:
    listener:
      ack-mode: manual-immediate
      concurrency: 1
      type: batch
    consumer:
...
```

Adding `type: batch` tells the framework that you want the full batch of records.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem was pretty simple. I was missing the spring.kafka.listener.type configuration pararmeter. Found the answer here: